# Convert object Values to upper case

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects

I have an object that I'm retrieving by doing JSON.stringify(myObject)

Now I want to convert all values (not keys) to upper case.

How can I do it in the best way possible in **TypeScript**?

```
myObj = {
  "name":"John",
  "age":30,
  "cars": [
    { "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
    { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] }
  ]
 }
```

TO

```
 myObj = {
  "name":"JOHN",
  "age":30,
  "cars": [
    { "name":"FORD", "models":[ "FIESTA", "FOCUS", "MUSTANG" ] },
    { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] }
  ]
 }
```

I already looked at this, but maybe there are a nicest way to achieve this. -> [How to convert JSON string values to lowercase in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37638200/how-to-convert-json-string-values-to-lowercase-in-javascript)

Comment: 1. TypeScript doesn't "do" anything by itself. It compiles code down to JavaScript and ensures type safety at compile time. It also adds some extra syntax that still resolves to normal JS. Basically, you need JavaScript code to do this. 2. What you have is **not** JSON. You have a plain JavaScript object. JSON is a serialisation format that is text - every single JSON is a string. 3. You never do `JSON.stringify` in your code. You just have a plain JS object - since it's not a string, it hasn't been through a `JSON.stringify` call.

Answer (score 6):

Just do a deep iteration trough your object and call toUpperCase() function for string values, like this:

```
var myObj = {
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30,
    "cars": [
        { "name": "Ford", "models": ["Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang"] },
        { "name": "BMW", "models": ["320", "X3", "X5"] }
    ]
};

function iterate(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj[key] !== null && typeof obj[key] === "object") {
            iterate(obj[key]);
        } else if (obj[key] !== null && typeof obj[key] === "string") {
            obj[key] = obj[key].toUpperCase();
        }
    }
}

iterate(myObj);
```